# How do I use superscript and subscript characters in questions?

Tags: support, markdown

When I need to ask questions, occasionally, I'll need a super or a subscript letter or number for pseudo-code or math equations.

I've seen this done in answers of this question: [Special superscript characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18484623)

I've gone through the formatting page and for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: For future reference, you can view the source of any question by clicking the 'edit' button below it (or the 'improve this answer' if not logged in).

Comment: Although, in that example, it's not superscript, it appears to be some unicode derivative.

Comment: That question uses the actual Unicode codepoints for superscript characters; it’s not just formatting. If you want a superscript 2, for example, there’s one of those: ² Works in comments, too.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in comments?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use `<sup>` and `<sub>`:

```
This is a <sup>superscript</sup>  
This is a <sub>subscript</sub>
```

This is a <sup>superscript</sup>
This is a <sub>subscript</sub>

Using `<pre><code>` blocks, because they're strange, lets you do this as well:

```
<pre><code>This is a <sup>superscript</sup>  
This is a <sub>subscript</sub></code></pre>
```

```
This is a superscript  
This is a subscript
```

But it's an evil hack and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Okay, so is that only usable for regular text? From your example it seems as if it doesn't apply to the code section.

Comment: @PaulBakerSaltShaker correct - the point of a code block is to show the source. If you put it inside a `<pre><code>` block however, or use unicode like the other question did, it is possible to have them in there, let me edit my answer for an example.

Comment: Okay thanks, I get it now. This makes a lot more sense than it did before. I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Oooooh! Evil hacks are fun to know.

Comment: Do <sup>sup</sup> and <sub>sub</sub> work in comments, too? Crap. No.

Comment: @DavidConrad I notice that on biology.stackexchange.com you can do $O_2$ and it will do the 2 as subscript.

Comment: Broken on May 18, 2017.

Comment: @barlop CO_2 doesn't work within a math equation on Chemistry Stack Exchange but CO_{2} does.

Comment: This is buggy when I need to show backticks in fenced code. It messes up the text when switching between Rich Text mode and Markdown mode. Reproduction (note there are 4 backticks around the code: <sup><sub>silly way to run a cmd ``` `which python` ```</sub></sup>

Comment: @AmitNaidu It does work with backticks — and all the other shorthand e.g. `*italic*`, `**bold**` — **if** you insert whitespace line padding after the opening `<sub>` tag and before the closing `</sub>` tag. For example, see the subscript block I added to the bottom of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482549/gnome-screenshot-gui-which-command-launches-that/482550#482550

Comment: How to do this in comments?

Answer (score 4):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18497433/1281433) to that question says

> For instance, here on SO, you could use: <sup>demo superscript ABC</sup>
>   That's the output of `<sup>demo superscript ABC</sup>`

You can also use `<sub>…</sub>` for sub<sub>scripting</sub>.

Answer (score 4):

In the new [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release) the shortcuts for the Superscript <kbd>Ctrl-.</kbd> and Subscript <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd> are introduced.  Reference: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51
Using the new shortcuts you are able to create the Superscript and Subscript texts.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Superscript, Subscript image]

**GIF for reference:**

[image: Superscript, Subscript gif]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode superscript numbers (⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹) or html `<sup>2</sup>` (but that doesn't work in comments). It seems that *some* parts of SE are using something called [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to render math symbols / formulas including superscript.  Here are [some examples](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but they won't work unless mathjax is enabled.

Comment: For example, this doesn't work here on meta.stackexchange: $x_i^2$, bit it will work in math for example.