# Announcing the Stacks Editor Beta release!

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, announcements, stacks-editor

**TL;DR:** The Stacks Editor Beta release rolled out on July 5, 2022! To see [what we've been working on](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md), what we are working on, and what we plan to work on, check out [the Stacks Editor repo on GitHub](https://github.com/orgs/StackExchange/projects/1). The editor is still an opt-in feature, and there is currently no timeline for a network-wide deployment.

---

### This question is no longer being monitored for new answers. If you have further bug reports or feature requests for the new Stacks Editor, please post them as new questions tagged [stacks-editor](/questions/tagged/stacks-editor).

---

Back in early 2021, [we announced the launch of the Alpha version for a new Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/208518). The announcement post saw a lot of activity, and after a lot of work by our Stacks Team, we're ready to launch the Stacks Editor into its Beta version!

In the original announcement for the Alpha Version of the new editor, Catija highlighted some of the reasons why we needed to create a new editor, ranging from meeting our Teams users' needs to simplifying future dev work on the public sites (you can read more in [the original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/208518)). We asked you to test it and provide feedback — and you did. The post gathered 110+ answers with bug reports, feature requests, and more general feedback provided by you.

The team worked hard to respond to your feedback, but after a while, public feedback from the team about what was being worked on slowed to a near halt. While the team was still working silently on the Stacks Editor during this time, they had to balance this work with other priorities on their plate. More importantly, though, and as I mentioned above, we ended up not updating you on where work on the editor was and where we were planning on going with it: this doesn't reflect well on us, and we apologize. We'll aim to be more proactive and frequent with communications on this going forward. This brings us to this post.

As [Yaakov mentioned earlier in June](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418491/1328704), the Stacks Editor is the main editor used in the new Ask Question Wizard, which will be made available on Stack Overflow sometime after the Beta 2 release goes out. The new Wizard, in turn, will later be a central piece of [the Staging Ground project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/1328704). So where are we going next?

### Roadmap

You can have a look at [the Stacks Editor repo on GitHub](https://github.com/orgs/StackExchange/projects/1) to see a breakdown by feature of what's been worked on and what is still to come (issues in the “No Milestone” section are backlogged, with no projected pick-up date). To give you a high-level overview:

- ****Alpha 2**:** This is what the team's been silently building and shipping since the original Alpha release of the editor. The editors used on network sites were updated to include this release on June 21, 2022. The team’s worked to fix many of the issues reported by you, including:

  - some issues caused by flipping from the Markdown mode (MD) to the Rich Text (RT) mode, and back (examples [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360097/208518), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360095/208518), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360159/208518));
  - issues with [tooltips obscuring the editor area on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360175/208518);
  - and [Enter key oddities in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360036/208518).
- **Beta 1:** This was released on July 5, 2022 and is in production as of July 12. [Full release notes](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases/tag/v0.6.0) are available. The main accomplishment of this release is to ensure the back-end library is feature-complete as compared to the old editor — meaning the Stacks team laid the groundwork that’ll allow the dev teams responsible for the Public Q&A sites to work on Stack Exchange-specific functionality. With this, the latter teams will be able in the future to build plugins into the editor, with the goal of reaching feature-parity (for all sites) to the old editor available on the network. Some of the issues addressed on this release were:

  - [adding initial support for a Markdown preview pane](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/115) — we know this was a big pain point for many of our power users. Happy to announce that [preview mode is now available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode);
  - enhancements to link insertion and editing, as per the issues reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360037/208518) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360047/208518);
  - [triple-clicking selecting the whole text in Markdown mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360115/208518);
  - and [adding official external plugin support](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/111), which will be required for supporting various extra editor features across the Stack Exchange network, such as poker, go, chess, code snippets, and MathJax.
- **Beta 2:** This was released on July 28, 2022, and the editor was released on participating sites on August 8, 2022. For this release, we identified some issues we feel should be addressed before launching the Ask Wizard and Staging Ground projects. This release also included some issues that were reported in answers to this post. Some of the highlights for this release are ([full release notes also available](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases/tag/v0.7.0)):

  - [Improvements to code block indentations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360083/208518);
  - An overhaul to the code highlighting system that addresses a number of issues reported with highlights to Markdown mode when text isn’t CommonMark compliant, as reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360153/208518), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360050/208518), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360038/208518).
  - A change in the toggle between Rich Text and MarkDown modes - the toggle is now icon-based, instead of the on-off switch that had been in place up until now.
  - Bug fixes with image-uploads ([here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/167) and [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/167)), [code block serialization](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/168).
  - Block elements are now [allowed inside list items](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/63).
- **Beta 3:** These are issues that would be beneficial to address, but not required for baseline functionality. Once these are addressed, the Stacks Editor should be ready for a network-wide deployment (though we don’t currently have any plans to do that; more on that below). There isn’t a timeline for addressing these issues, and the team will tackle them as their bandwidth permits. Highlights for this release include:

  - [adding the ability to change the code block language in Rich Text mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360147/208518);
  - [using a different resize anchor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376613/208518);
  - and [some issues with line breaks in tables, that occur when switching from Markdown to Rich Text and back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360648/208518).

Until the end of July 2022, we have members of the Stacks team as well as devs from one of the teams responsible for Public Q&A assigned to working on the issues marked as essential for the Beta 2 release. Additionally, there’s some flexibility on that roadmap to account for high-priority issues reported in response to this post, and though we can’t guarantee we’ll be able to address every single thing reported, we’ll be responding to all feedback as we triage it and, all applicable unique issues will be logged in [the Stacks-Editor repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues). Once July’s over, we’ll still be monitoring and responding to issues and feature requests surrounding the Stacks editor, be them reported on MSO or MSE (which can be brought to staff attention using [this process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/208518)), or on GitHub (more on how to report issues at the bottom of the post). These will be triaged based on severity and developer availability to prioritize issues for the Beta 2 release.

### FAQ

#### What was that about a network-wide deployment?

As I mentioned above, the Stacks Editor is a central piece of the new Ask Question Wizard and Staging Ground, so for now we’re committing resources to ensure the work needed to support that project is successful. Additionally, we’re expecting you will report many more issues that have yet to be identified, and have to be prepared to be able to address those issues and respond to those reports. For that reason, **at the moment we don’t have any timeline to roll out the Stacks Editor network-wide**, and are instead focusing on ensuring we can undertake the near term work required to support the Ask Question Wizard and Staging Ground project. When we get to the point where it looks like extending the opt-in testing to questions, or even a network-wide deployment *might* be in sight, we’ll make sure to loop you in.

#### Is this still opt-in?

Yes! The editor will continue to be available on Stack Overflow for Teams, and for answering questions on Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange — this is reached via an opt-in on the [Profile > Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) page labeled “Enable new editor” (the text here will be updated soon to change the “Alpha” label into a “Beta” label). When the Ask Wizard is released on Stack Overflow, all users will be able to toggle into this question asking mode, where they’ll be able to try out the Editor in that context as well (more details around this will be shared on MSO when the release is made).

#### How to provide feedback

We will be monitoring this post for responses until the end of July 2022. If you have feedback, bugs to report, or feature requests, please post them as an answer under this question — with one issue per answer. Please make sure what you’re posting here hasn’t been posted already, and do not report issues in comments. Please provide steps needed to reliably reproduce a bug, along with which browser/s you're experiencing the bug in. If an issue on the [Alpha Release post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) doesn't have a link to an active case on GitHub (GH) feel free to repost here and link to the original in the report. If it does have a link to an active case it is being worked on so there is no need to repost here. Additionally, since this is an open-source project, you can also use the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues) for the editor to [submit new issues](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/new/choose) if you feel comfortable doing so — we'll cross-link stuff reported here and in the GH repo. As mentioned above, you can also use the repo to check out the issues still [scheduled for work](https://github.com/orgs/StackExchange/projects/1). After July 2022, issues should be reported as separate questions tagged [stacks-editor](/questions/tagged/stacks-editor).

Comment: I have updated the statuses on all old posts/answers to reflect what was completed and released in Alpha 2 and Beta 1.

Comment: I am a bit annoyed. How did I miss that y'all finally decided to include a preview pane, which is the main thing I miss from the old editor 

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You didn't miss it. This is the first time that we announced a preview pane. It is built into the editor not (you can [try it out here](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/md-preview.html)), but it still needs some tweaks and integration work to get it to work on the sites. There will be a separate post about it when it is ready to go.

Comment: Not quite a feature request proper - and more for the future but for the sake of clarity - especially during the beta phase, and as/when the new editor is more widely used, would it be sensible to have the current version somewhere for the ease of classification of bug reports between versions?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you can always try out the current version at https://editor.stackoverflow.design/ (this will always be the same version as on-site, except for the slight lag between when a new version is released for the editor and has not yet hit the site).

Comment: can implement fira code or any font with ligature in code??? https://i.imgur.com/mOO2sOM.png

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 we don't have plans for custom font support in the code editor.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Summary of bugs / feature requests posted as answers

Want to contribute? Great! But please read the notes at the bottom of the table first.

| Type | Summary | Status | GitHub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [License written in lower case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380326/665544) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Too much space between "Draft saved" / Community wiki checkbox and bottom edge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380298/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Markdown display does not consider escaped * or _ when displaying text in italics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380383/513150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#21](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Preview does not support lang-* notation for syntax highlighting specification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380381/513150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#21](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Headings are not always shown as headings in Markdown mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380339/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#21](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Blank lines are removed when switching modes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380413/665544) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#152](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/152) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Switching modes causes links to be sorted in wrong order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380305/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#163](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/163) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Inserting an image never works the first time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380303/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#167](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/167) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Switching modes combines adjacent code blocks added in rich text mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380302/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#168](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/168) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Undo/redo buttons always look enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380329/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#172](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/172) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bibliography style hyperlinked image Markdown is partially broken when toggling Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380380/513150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#188](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/188) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [No room for contents in the image uploader while editing on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380542/513150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#202](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/202) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Misplaced link edit tooltip after cancelling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380336/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#193](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/193) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bare links in a list (in the rich text view) are prefixed with a loading spinner on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380379/513150) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tag markup with disallowed characters is incorrectly rendered as a valid tag in the rich text view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380509/513150) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) | [#201](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/201) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Weird behaviour when using the inline code button multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380325/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Weird behaviour with quotes and source fences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380331/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#70](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/70) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Copying text from one list bullet to another inserts the pasted text as a new sub-bullet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380300/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#164](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/164) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Heading button's tooltip (Ctrl-h) is hidden by the list of heading options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380301/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#169](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/169) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Weird behaviour when dragging to select a link in the rendered view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380310/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#170](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/170) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Heading disappears when applying blockquote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380318/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#171](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/171) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Switching modes has problems with asterisks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380316/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#173](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/173) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Pasting Markdown into the Markdown editor causes it to be surrounded by code fences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380334/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#174](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/174) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [HTML comments disappear when switching modes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380319/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#175](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/175) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Cursor gets stuck after inserting link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380333/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#178](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/178) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [HTML backtick entity is incorrectly converted when switching modes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380357/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#180](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/180) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Code blocks in numbered lists render incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380355/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#181](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/181) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Adding a [code block / heading / blockquote / table] on the same line as a [bullet / numbered] point is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380344/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#181](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/181) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Standard HTML does not render properly in the rich text view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380346/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#183](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/183) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Quoting table removes leading pipes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380367/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#185](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/185) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Triple backticks can't be wrapped in source fence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380356/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#186](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/186) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Ctrl+Shift+Z is undo instead of redo... unless there are no more items to undo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380386/513150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#187](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/187) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Only one table can be deleted at a time when trying to delete multiple tables at once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380419/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#189](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/189) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Dragging to select text in the "Edit image" dialog box is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380422/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#190](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/190) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Pressing the down arrow key in a code block with multiple lines moves out of the code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380352/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#191](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/191) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Inserting a horizontal rule in Markdown mode makes the previous line a header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380338/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#192](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/192) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Various oddities occur when a numbered item is a child of a bulleted item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380396/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#194](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/194) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [HTML comment inserts blue bar on top of post in rich text mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380409/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#195](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/195) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Adding a link to text with a space at the end causes the space to be included in the link text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380335/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#196](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/196) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [No way to escape source fence at beginning of post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380418/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#197](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/197) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [In rich text `<hr>` doesn't have selection highlight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380447/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#198](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/198) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Moving cursor over `<hr>` pushes it down in rich text mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380438/665544) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#199](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/199) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [In rich text, selecting blocks moves edit image dialogue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380439/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#200](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/200) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Cursor disappears in long posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380570/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#206](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/206) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [RT mode weirdly displays content made from HTML paragraph and HTML comment tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380659/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#207](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/207) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Tags should be automatically rendered when first typing it in the rendered view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380307/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#51](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Applying a [numbered / bulleted] list to multiple lines works differently in each mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380604/513150) |  |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Pressing italics on bold text removes bold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382266) |  |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Only one spoiler can be revealed at a time in the rich text view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380345/295232) | [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Bolded message in Markdown is already bolded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380463/513150) | [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Placeholder text in edit summary is missing a bracket for mobile users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380466/513150) | [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Removing code-block formatting results in broken state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380337/295232) | [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) | [#179](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/179) |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Imgur logo not aligned with preceding text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380327/295232) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Switching modes destroys the undo/redo stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380473/513150) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |  |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | [Multiple leading spaces render as spaces in rich-text mode, but turn into a code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380353/295232) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Update the Alpha label to the Beta label in the Preferences tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380565/513150) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Improve keyboard shortcut capitalization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380296/295232) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) | [#166](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/166) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Code button should indent/unindent things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380312/295232) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) | [#50](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/50) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Make the resize tool more (visually) accessible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380441/513150) | [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) | [#101](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/101) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [In rich text mode, either help icon should not direct to markdown help or help page should mention both rich text + markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380568/513150) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Inconsistent header levels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380299/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#165](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/165) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Allow saving edits to a post using with Ctrl+Enter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380313/295232) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) | [#205](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/205) |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [We should be able to drag the question right above the answer](/a/380465) | [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Consider not including the strikethrough button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380412/513150) | [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Capitalize syntax highlight language to source code fence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380343/295232) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Sort reference's numbering by order of appearance in post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380402/665544) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |  |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | [Add a visual formula editor as an editor feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380654/513150) | [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) |  |
| [support](/questions/tagged/support) | [When will the editor be activated for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380321/295232) | [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) |  |

#### Notes

- Anybody is welcome to contribute to this post; it's a Community wiki after all.
- Sorting order: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) > [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) > [support](/questions/tagged/support), then [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) > [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) >  [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) > [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) > no status tag > [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) > [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) > [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).
- Comments can be used to discuss the structure of this post, e.g. whether the sort order above makes sense or needs to be improved.

#### Credits

Original idea: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396655/4751173), further refined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148/295232) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698/295232).

#### Updates

Run the snippet below to check if this summary is up to date, or which changes are needed.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

const summaryAnswerID = 380354; // ID of the summary answer
const key = "U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw(("; // taken from API documentation
const typeTagRegex = /\[(meta-)?tag:(discussion|support|feature-request|bug)\]/i;
const statusTagRegex = /\[(meta-)?tag:(status-[-\w]+)\]/i;
const summaryRegex = /#+\s+(.*)/i;
const gitHubLinkRegex = /\/\/github.com\/\S+\/issues\/(\d+)/i;
const site = "meta";

async function main() {
  // Find question ID and current summary
  var result = await $.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers/" + summaryAnswerID + "?site=" + site + "&filter=!nKzQURFm*e&key=" + key);
  let questionID = result.items[0]["question_id"];
  let summaryBody = result.items[0]["body"];
  let summaryMarkdown = result.items[0]["body_markdown"];
  let lines = summaryMarkdown.split(/\r?\n/);
  
  var linesToAdd = [];
  var linesToChange = {};
  var page = 0;
  while (true) {
    // Fetch answers
    result = await $.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/380295/answers?page=" + ++page +
        "&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&site=" + site + "&filter=!nKzQURFm*e&key=" + key);
    for (let item of result.items) {
      // Summary?
      let answerID = item["answer_id"];
      if (answerID == summaryAnswerID)
        continue;
      
      // Present in summary?
      var currentLine = null;
      for (let line of lines) {
        if (line.search(new RegExp('/a/' + answerID + '[/)]')) != -1) {
          currentLine = line;
          break;
        }
      }
      
      // Analyze answer
      let markdown = item["body_markdown"];
      let typeTagMatch = typeTagRegex.exec(markdown);
      let summaryMatch = summaryRegex.exec(markdown);
      let statusTagMatch = statusTagRegex.exec(markdown);
      let gitHubLinkMatch = gitHubLinkRegex.exec(markdown);      
      
      if (currentLine == null) {
        // Generate new entry
        let title = summaryMatch == null ? "(please add summary)" : summaryMatch[1];
        let summary = "[" + title + "](/a/" + answerID + ")";        
        linesToAdd.push(generateLine(typeTagMatch, summary, statusTagMatch, gitHubLinkMatch));
      } else {
        // Compare against summary
        let components = currentLine.split("|");
        let typeTag = typeTagRegex.exec(components[1].trim());
        let summary = components[2].trim();
        let statusTag = statusTagRegex.exec(components[3].trim());
        let gitHubLink = gitHubLinkRegex.exec(components[4].trim()); // may be absent, if GitHub isn't used
        var changeNeeded = typeTagMatch != null && (typeTag == null || typeTag[2].toLowerCase() != typeTagMatch[2].toLowerCase());
        changeNeeded |= statusTagMatch != null && (statusTag == null || statusTag[2].toLowerCase() != statusTagMatch[2].toLowerCase());
        changeNeeded |= gitHubLinkMatch != null && (gitHubLink == null || gitHubLink[1].toLowerCase() != gitHubLinkMatch[1].toLowerCase());
        if (!changeNeeded)
          continue;
        
        linesToChange[currentLine] = generateLine(typeTagMatch, summary, statusTagMatch, gitHubLinkMatch);
      }
    }
    
    // Any more answers?
    if (!result["has_more"])
      break;
  }
  
  // Changes needed?
  if (linesToAdd.length == 0 && Object.keys(linesToChange).length == 0) {
    alert("The summary is up-to-date.");
    return;
  }  
  var messages = [];
  if (linesToAdd.length != 0) {
    messages.push("\nThe following lines need to be added:");
    for (let lineToAdd of linesToAdd) {
      messages.push(lineToAdd);
    }
  }
  if (Object.keys(linesToChange).length != 0) {
    messages.push("\nThe following lines need to be changed:");
    for (let lineToChange in linesToChange) {
      messages.push("\n" + lineToChange + "\n-->\n" + linesToChange[lineToChange] + "\n");
    }
  }  
  console.log(messages.join("\n"));
  alert("Changes needed, please check the console for details.")
}
main();

function generateLine(typeTagMatch, summary, statusTagMatch, gitHubLinkMatch) {
  var components = [""];
  components.push(typeTagMatch == null ? "(please add type)" : "[tag:" + typeTagMatch[2] + "]");
  components.push(summary);
  components.push(statusTagMatch == null ? "" : "[tag:" + statusTagMatch[2] + "]");
  if (gitHubLinkMatch != null) {
    components.push("[#" + gitHubLinkMatch[1] + "](https:" + gitHubLinkMatch[0] + ")");
  }
  components.push("");
  return components.join(" | ").trim();
}
```

Comment: @Glorfindel: That's one heck of a snippet you got there. Works like a charm! I've not added [the post that needs to be added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380465/513150) because it's a duplicate of an existing report.

Comment: The snippet doesn't render as a snippet when using the new editor, just plain code (it [removes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/380354/80) the `<!-- language: lang-[html/js] -->` block upon posting or switching between modes). I fixed the snippet by switching back to the old editor.

Answer (score 41):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #163](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/163) [Commit `20f338a`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/commit/20f338abea66dcaedc1157adb2cb91b223869bb5)

Toggling Markdown off and back on causes reference-style Markdown links to be re-sorted into alphabetical order rather than [natural order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/).

[image: Screen recording of numbered links being reordered from the correct order to 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, etc.]

Comment: [Source of the problem](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/d6de2d4bfca63a6a7b9c729c2747833bf91aa777/src/shared/markdown-serializer.ts#L70). Ideally, the original order should be preserved.

Comment: [Related feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380402).

Answer (score 28):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #164](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/164)

Copying text from one list bullet to another inserts the pasted text as a new sub-bullet.

[image: Screen recording demonstrating the above-described bug]

Comment: This is particularly vexing when composing review suspension messages, which use the new editor *and* whose content consists largely of a bulleted list of reviews.  You can work around it somewhat by using Ctrl+Shift+V to paste without formatting, but then you can't copy the useful parts of the formatting.

Comment: Also reproduced on Firefox on MacOS, cc @YaakovEllis

Answer (score 24):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #167](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/167)

Inserting an image never works the first time; you always have to cancel the image insertion dialog and re-do it.  This happens with both copy/paste and drag & drop.  Tested in Firefox 104.0a1 on Windows 10.

[image: A screen recording of an image file being dragged onto the Stacks editor, resulting in a blank image upload dialog. Once it is canceled, the process is repeated, and it shows the thumbnail properly.]

Comment: Also reported as a separate post here: [New Stacks Editor doesn't let me upload images at first try](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379709/new-stacks-editor-doesnt-let-me-upload-images-at-first-try)

Comment: Also fails on MacOS. The only way to get this to work directly is to open the image dialogue, and paste an image in there.

Comment: Also doesn't work the first time when _pasting_ an image. Even worse, if you try to paste a _different_ image in the second time, it uploads the first one ‍♂️

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine is that a separate issue? I've noticed if you focus on the image upload bit it works first time with a paste?

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #168](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/168)

Toggling Markdown on and off combines adjacent code blocks added in rich text mode.

[image: Screen recording of two adjacent code blocks shown in rich-text mode, then Markdown mode is toggled on and off, and they are combined into one]

Comment: Wasn't this, or something very much like this, fixed in the original alpha release?

Comment: I wonder if a more robust solution here would be to serialize the code blocks into Markdown with the triple-backtick codeblocks (`\`\`\``) instead of pure whitespace indentation. The code block button in Markdown mode already does this, and has the added benefit of being able to specify the syntax highlighting manually (`\`\`\`css`).

Comment: Either way, we still should be able to insure we preserve that indentation-free line in between the code blocks when round-tripping between Markdown and Rich Text modes.

Comment: @TylerMcEntee Addind a fence in rich text is likely the only chance because per CommonMark specification one empty line on the same indentation level does not break a code block.

Comment: @TylerMcEntee That you don't insure round trips from Markdown->rich text->Markdown *always* preserve things *exactly* as they were in the Markdown source is a *huge* portion of the fundamental problems with this editor. If you were insuring preservation in all cases, then a large number of your bugs wouldn't exist and people would be substantially more comfortable using this editor. Combined with having no preview *other than* switching to rich text mode (i.e. that to *preview requires corrupting the Markdown*) is one of the major reasons there's been such a negative response to this editor.

Answer (score 20):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #166](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/166)

The keyboard shortcuts use lower case for the letter keys, e.g. "Cmd-h" on macOS or "Ctrl-h" on Windows:

[image]

Could you switch that to upper case - that is much more common across the internet, and even used that way here, e.g. in the regular keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: I would say that if the keyboard shortcut does *not* work if you press, say, Cmd-Shift-h, then this should *not* be done. Without the double negative, only change them to upper case if using them with an upper case letter works.

Comment: @HereticMonkey please have a look at your keyboard. The keys have upper case letters, right? Nobody gets confused that it usually produces lower case letters. I'm not really confused either, except when it comes to things like "Cmd+l" - is that a lower case `l` or an upper case `I`? Therefore, consistency is key, and keyboard shortcuts (almost?) always use upper case.

Comment: It isn't only case. The notation is a remnant from [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs). A more common notation is `Ctrl + H` or `Ctrl+H` (without space). The existing editor (and [the Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) and many others) uses the latter, e.g. ***"Strong <strong> Ctrl+B"***.

Comment: ([More examples from](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_default-keyboard-shortcuts) Visual Studio Code documentation.)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Emacs would write `C-h` for "Ctrl+H" or `M-h` for "Cmd+H." For example, the save chord is `C-x s`, which modern shortcut notation would write as "Ctrl+X, S," and the copy chord is `M-w`, or "Cmd/Alt+W."

Comment: @HereticMonkey A keyboard shortcut like `ctrl`-`v` tends to work even if caps lock is on. Therefore, the case of the `s` doesn't matter. `ctrl`-`shift`-`v` is a separate keyboard shortcut that works regardless of whether caps lock is on or off, it is more helpful to spell out the `shift` button rather than omit it and hope that the reader understands that a capital S indicates that the shift button should be pressed (regardless of caps lock mode).

Answer (score 17):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #165](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/165)

In Rich Text mode, we can choose different header levels:

[image]

In Markdown mode, we only have one, the H1:

[image]

Can we have that dropdown in Markdown mode too? And since (IIRC) the switch to CommonMark, we now have six levels of supported headers. It might make sense to add those too.

Comment: Additionally: could we consider removing Heading 1 from the list?  It is obnoxiously large, putting it on the same level as the page title.  It *definitely* should not be the default heading level that is applied in Markdown mode.

Comment: @RyanM I don't (think I) use it, but it feels weird to start the list with #2. Heck, as a programmer I'm already confused it doesn't start with 0 ...

Comment: A better alternative approach might be to silently translate the headers in the post source into one level lower.  For example, using Heading 1 would produce an `<h2>` tag, Heading 2 would produce `<h3>`, and so on.  Though that creates the question of how to best handle existing posts that already use headings.

Comment: Agree with @RyanM. WCAG accessibility guidelines advise that there should only be one `<h1>` tag on a webpage, which should be for the page title, which for SO is the question title. There should be no other `<h1>` tags on the page because screen readers don't handle multiple `<h1>` tags well.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There's too much space between "Draft saved" / Community wiki checkbox and the bottom edge of the new editor:

[image]

---

Compare with the old editor:

[image]

---

[Chrome (latest version) for Android and Windows (11)]

Comment: @Yaakov no GH entry for this one? (Asking because it's in status planned.)

Comment: No. It is logged internally, as it is an issue with how we use the stacks editor on the site, not an issue with the stacks editor itself.

Comment: We fixed this issue in the newest version of stacks editor. We hope it helps!

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #169](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/169)

The Heading button's tooltip (Ctrl-h) is hidden by the list of heading options (such as Heading 1, 2, 3).

[image: Overlap]

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #170](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/170)

There's some weird behaviour when dragging to select a link in the rendered view. The raw link in the popup is also selected:

[image]

---

[Chrome (latest version) on Windows 11]

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #171](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/171)

Selecting heading text (with the hashes) in the Markdown view and applying blockquotes using the Markdown button for blockquotes (or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) removes the hashes and renders it as normal text. This does not happen when applying blockquotes using the `>` character:

[image]

---

Also reported [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363589/513150) to *Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor*.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

1. In Markdown mode if you press the Inline code button a first time you get a pair of backticks:

[image: first press inline code button]

2. If you next press it a second time you get another pair of backticks:

[image: second press inline code button]

3. But if you press it a third time the second pair of backticks are just removed and you return to step 1.

Is this intended behavior? Should the second click in step 2 remove the backticks from step 1 instead of adding another pair? I fail to see the gain from a Markdown syntax POV in having 2 pairs of backticks, either you have a literal defined by 1 pair or a code fence defined by a pair of 3 backticks... Right?!

Also reproduced on https://editor.stackoverflow.design/ using Firefox 102.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: The removal of the backticks in your Step 3 is because you already have one set of backticks highlighted. The button at that point effectively functions as a toggle for inline code formatting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (windows chrome 103) on answers on the site or [the test editor](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/)

Comment: @YaakovEllis I think that was fixed yesterday since the dev acknowledged the behaviour? Maybe a fix was rolled out and it's `status-completed`?

Comment: I cannot repro on Firefox 102. Every time I try, regardless of browser, and regardless of keyboard shortcut or button, the text _with_ the backticks is highlighted after the first inline-code formatting, and then is completely un-backticked after clicking again.

Comment: I can confirm that this was not fixed yesterday (maybe it was fixed in the past). Do you still see it now?

Comment: @YaakovEllis yes, did it right now. Start with an empty line that has empty lines above and below, click the `Inline code` button 3 times without any text and it happens.

Comment: I get it now. It is happening when you click the "inline code" button with no text selected. Then (as happens with bold, italics, etc), only the text inside the new markup is selected, so as to allow the editor to just start typing and maintain the new formatting. When clicking the button again after doing nothing, it will do as you noted. I am mixed as to whether to mark this as a bug, by design, or wont-fix. We'll talk internally.

Comment: @YaakovEllis my suggestion: allow the 2nd click to revert back to the exact state that preceded the 1st click, if the user did nothing else in the meanwhile besides those 2 clicks.

Comment: @bad_coder I removed my earlier comment identifying this as a bug. After getting caught up on the comments this morning I realized I was applying my own selection over text, not clicking the Bold/Italic/Inline Code buttons in an empty editor. Like Yaakov said, it's a little more complicated than I previously alluded to.

Comment: @TylerMcEntee yes, the issue isn't obvious. The button works as a *"surround with markup"* shortcut, but next the text selection stops the more intuitive `undo` `Ctrl+z` functionality (the right choice is actually the keyboard, not the button). It's a UX issue and I'm left wondering how popular IDEs do it!? I think novice users (and rich text folks especially) will find the buttons unappealing because they're likely to expect a 2nd click undo, if they get it wrong they'll have to select, delete, so the mis-click/expectation will lead to overhead in undoing making for an unpleasant experience.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #172](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/172)

The undo/redo buttons (which may only show up on mobile?) always look enabled even if I haven't done anything:

[image: Undo/redo in black]

The table button however looks disabled because I selected some text in the answer.

They used to be disabled if there was nothing to undo/redo (though that had its own bugs).

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #51](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51)

Tags should be automatically rendered when first typing it in the *rendered* view.

[image]

This is what it looks like when switching to the Markdown view:

[image]

It only renders *after* posting the question / answer.

Comment: Hi @Justin, our next Beta release will include the ability to create tags in Rich-Text mode (along with subscript, superscript, and spoilers). We're tracking the issue here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #173](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/173)

Toggling from Markdown to rich text and back to Markdown causes asterisks (in the placeholder text for links) to be displaced.

[image]

---

Also reported [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362047/513150) to *Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor*.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #178](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/178)

In rich text mode **in Firefox only** if you insert a link and next try to move the cursor using the left arrow <kbd>←</kbd> starting from the right, **the cursor gets stuck and won't move past the second to last char in the link.**

The same doesn't happen however starting from the left side and using the right arrow <kbd>→</kbd> to cycle through the characters, in this case you can move across the text in the link and beyond.

[image]

Comment: Repro in Firefox 102. Works fine in Chrome 103.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #175](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/175)

The editor seems to support comments like `<!-- language-all: bash -->` but it's just not taking effect. A comment like `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` disappears when switching modes.

Code example:

```bash
Var "hello"
```

I have a comment above the code but it's still showing as "plaintext". System: iOS. Let me know if you can reproduce on other setups.

Comment: If you wait a second or so, it appears to correctly switch to bash formatting.  I also can't reproduce it losing the comment when switching modes, at least by editing your post.

Comment: @RyanM How many seconds? I've done my Mississippis and I've spent the time to write this comment and it still says "plaintext". It could be a browser specific thing.

Comment: [Very quick, within a second.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Irs.gif)  Firefox 104.0a1.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### Multiple leading spaces render as spaces in rich-text mode, but turn into a code block when pasted or after a round trip through Markdown mode

Honestly, I'm not sure what the best way to fix this is.  Non-breaking spaces, maybe?

[image: Screen recording of adding spaces to the start of a line, copying that line further into the post (resulting in a code block), then toggling Markdown mode on and off to turn the first one into a code block as well.]

Comment: I am thinking that once you add 4 leading space, it should automatically become a code-block. Thoughts?

Comment: @YaakovEllis That certainly solves the problem, but I'm not sure it's a useful feature in its own right (other than not having to remember the shortcut for a code block).  It may also introduce other problems.  If a user isn't expecting it, they'd probably try to backspace to undo whatever they just did.  It's maybe also worth considering what would happen if you did it to the line after a code block - should it add it to the code block or just make a new one?  Should that depend on whether the code block is fenced or indented?

Comment: I think it comes down to a philosophy question of whether you want the user to understand that they're editing Markdown (so 4 spaces = code block) or if it's just a normal rich-text editor that happens to serialize to Markdown (so 4 spaces = 4 spaces, and you should try to preserve what the user typed, such as with non-breaking spaces). Of course, the latter approach then raises the question of what to do if the user types multiple spaces *elsewhere* in a line. I think I personally lean slightly toward "spaces in a rich-text editor are just spaces", but reasonable minds may disagree.

Comment: I hear you. Spaces in RT should just be spaces. But then round-tripping leads to the obvious: "what do we do with these 4 leading spaces now" issue, which could end up being a `wont-fix`, since the fix isn't really obvious or intuitive. And switching them into non-breaking spaces is also not so great, since that is also changing their input.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #180](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/180)

Writing inline code which contains backticks in the old editor used to be really annoying, so I still instinctively default to writing HTML, like this:

```
<code>&#96;</code>
```

When I write that into the Markdown mode of the new editor, then switch to Rich mode, it displays correctly:

[image: screenshot of the new rich editor, showing an inline code element containing a single backtick]

but then when I switch back, it gets converted into completely broken markdown:

```
<code>` ` </code>`
```

This does not render correctly; it looks like:

> `

instead of

> `` ` ``

Comment: The way I've been writing backticks within inline code in the new editor is by wrapping the desired text with double backticks like this `\`\` this has \` single backtick  \`\``.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #174](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/174)

#### Pasting Markdown into the Markdown editor causes it to be surrounded by code fences.

While it's quite useful that pasted source code is auto-fenced, this should not happen if the source is Markdown.  It's not uncommon to compose longer or more complex posts outside the site (or to periodically copy their source out as a "backup").  Pasting the source should have the correct result.

To reproduce, copy the source of this question (I used [revision 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/b6998d97-6cc4-4d37-941f-9c93999329bf/view-source)) into an answer.

[image: Screen recording of Markdown being pasted into the Markdown editor, resulting in 3 backticks shown above it (they are also below it, but this is not captured). A switch to rich-text mode shows that it is rendered as a code block (auto-detected as VHDL)]

Comment: The text you copied is wrapped in a `pre`, hence the reason why the editor interpreted it as code.

Comment: This is reproducible regardless of the source of the copied text.  I reproduced it copying from: 1) the old editor, 2) the source link in the revisions list, 3) the new editor, 4) Visual Studio Code on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for code block function removing the code block for the entire code block.
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) for any text changes removing line breaks ([GH #179](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/179))

---

#### Removing code-block formatting results in broken state

Let's say I have text that is a mix of code and text.  I paste it in, and it's detected as a code block.  That's reasonable so far: it *did* contain code.  The problems occur when trying to fix it after removing the code block:

1. Selecting a portion of the text that was in the code block and clicking the code block button results in the entire text that was previously in the code block being converted back into a code block, rather than only the selected portion. This works correctly when the text in question has not previously been a code block.
2. Typing *anything* into the text that was previously a code block causes all line breaks to be immediately removed.

[image: Screen recording of the above described bug, reproducing bug 1 first, then bug 2]

Comment: @YaakovEllis re: *"status-bydesign for code block function removing the code block for the entire code block."* I expected that part.  The unexpected part is that after removing it, I cannot select only part of the text that was *previously* in the code block to add a *new* code block.

Comment: I have updated the GH issue to make note of that (I suspect that it is the same underlying issue, so keeping them together there).

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #181](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/181)

#### Code blocks in numbered lists render incorrectly, and are further broken by toggling Markdown mode on and off

To reproduce, create a post with this content:

```markdown
You can solve this in the following ways:

1.     println("Hello, world!")

2.     System.out.println("Hello, world!")
```

The correct rendering of this, as shown by the old editor, is:
[image: The above post rendered with the code blocks in-line with the numbers]

The new rich-text editor initially renders the code blocks on a new line from the number (but still correctly indented).  When Markdown mode is turned back on, it has moved the items onto new lines.  When it is switched back to rich-text mode a second time, the indentation is now lost.

[image: Screen recording of the above-described bug]

Comment: This is the same issue as described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380344/513150

Comment: @Justin I dont think that that is the same. Here is a specific scenario with list items. And that is with indented code blocks.

Comment: @Yaakov: The issue is the same in the sense that adding indented code or code blocks (and headings, blockquotes, etc.) on **the same line** as the numbered or bullet point is not possible. Switching between modes just shifts the formatted text on a new line.

Comment: @Justin you will notice that I put them in the same GH issue

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #188](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/188)

Bibliography style hyperlinked image Markdown is partially broken when toggling Markdown:

```
[![Profile Picture][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOU20s.png
```

[image: Profile Picture]

Becomes:

```
[![Profile Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOU20s.png)][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOU20s.png
```

GIF:
[image: GIF of a hyperlinked image with bibliography style link markdown becoming partially inline linked and partially bibliographically linked]

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #21](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21)

Markdown display does not consider escaped * or _ when displaying text in italics

Markdown:

```
Markdown view shows **bold** and *italics*, however it doesn't consider escaped \* all of this is now displayed in italics even though the "\*" was escaped. Now notice we are no longer in italics because of the final escaped asterisk. This also applies to "\_" escaped underscores... Switching between modes does not resolve this.
```

The Markdown View Looks like:
[image: Image of markdown view of the above text]

How it renders:

Markdown view shows **bold** and *italics*, however it doesn't consider escaped * all of this is now displayed in italics even though the "*" was escaped. Now notice we are no longer in italics because of the final escaped asterisk. This also applies to "_" escaped underscores... Switching between modes does not resolve this.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #187](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/187)

#### <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is undo instead of redo...unless there are no more items to undo

I would expect this to behave identically to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> (redo), as it does everywhere else (Firefox 104.0a1 on Windows 10).  At any rate, it certainly should not *sometimes* undo and *sometimes* redo.

[image: A screen recording of "Testing" "One" "Two" being typed each on one line. Then "One" and "Two" vanish, and "Testing" begins flashing]

Comment: Same behaviour with `⌘ Cmd` + `Shift` + `Z` on Chrome 103.0.5060.114 on macOS Monterey. So not OS or browser specific.

Comment: *sigh* One of my continuous frustrations with the existing editor is that SE has chosen to (poorly) implement their own "undo" feature and override the browser/system based ctrl-Z/ctrl-Y behavior. IMO, the browser/system based undo is what should be used. It's what users are *expecting* to happen, because it's what happens *everywhere else* in all the other applications they are using, even in other places on the site.

Comment: We have just released a new version of of the editor which supports `Cmd/Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Z` hot key for history redo.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [GH #50](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/50)

I use the code button really often to indent and unindent things, but that doesn't work in the new editor. It usually adds backticks instead. Can there be a button to indent and unindent on code sites?

You can try to edit this post.

### Block 1:

```
Try and format this not as code
Try it!
```

You can, but it's not intuitive because the one button (first `<>`) is disabled and you have to use preview mode. The fact that there is a second button to do code is not obvious.

### Block 2:

```
            Really indented
```

This appears to work but only as long as you remain in preview mode.

### Block 3:

```
This is indented enough
    This is indented too much
    Try and make it match the first line
```

You can't fix code that has bad indentation like above.

Comment: I completely agree that having an indent button would be helpful; that said, hopefully, when the code button finally starts adding fences instead of indents, we won't _have_ to fix the indents on most posts anymore, because they'll be using fences to begin with (One can dream, at least).

Comment: This was already requested [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360083) with a less explicit example.

Comment: @zcoop98 No matter what they do, it's still useful for old posts and posts that have horrible indentation inside the code fence.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #181](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/181)

Adding a [code block / heading / blockquote / table] on the **same line** as a [bullet / numbered] point is not possible in the new editor.

In the rich text view, the buttons are disabled when trying to do so:

[image]

When adding the [code block / heading / blockquote / table] on the same line as the [bullet / numbered] point in the Markdown view and switching to the rich text view, the formatted text is rendered on a new line rather than on the same line as the [bullet / numbered] point:

[image]

---

Comparison with the old editor for reference:

- Table:

  [image]
- Blockquote:

  [image]
- Heading:

  [image]
- Code block:

  [image]

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #190](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/190)

In the rich text view, editing an image link or image text in the "Edit image" dialog box works, but *dragging* to **select text** in any of the sections in the dialog box is not possible. Instead, it drags the entire dialog box as if the dialog box itself was being treated as an image (if you notice, dragging the dialog box also drags the (unicorn) image).

Workarounds to select text in any section:

1. Keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>.
2. Double/triple click on the desired text.

##### GIF for reference:

[image]

---

[Chrome (latest version) on Windows 11]

Comment: I think it isn't supposed to have "text dragging". The text in those 3 fields can be copy-pasted but where would you drag it to? The 3 fields don't have much usefulness outside of the picture they're part of.

Comment: @bad_coder: I didn't mean literally dragging the text. I meant dragging to just *select* the text (so it can be edited, copied, etc.).

Comment: That follows the usual UX after you apply copy-paste the selection, It's not a good idea to have the UX turn drag&drop into a copy-paste because you'll risk loosing the clipboard.

Comment: @bad_coder: I really don't understand what you're talking about.. The bug report is simple: Dragging to **select the text** is not possible in the dialog box. Have you tried selecting the text by dragging your mouse over the text?

Comment: Trying to drag to select some text ends up dragging the entire dialog box as if it were being treated as an image.

Comment: No it doesn't. At least in Firefox if you select the image you can drag&drop, in the gif you aren't selecting the image just clicking on it, so the UX is correct.

Comment: I'm not clicking on the *image*, rather the popup that shows up. And I'm not clicking at all. Rather, I'm trying to drag my mouse over, for example, the text in the Image description section. But it's not working because the popup seems to be attached to the image; dragging the popup also drags the image. I don't know of any popups on this site that act in this way.

Comment: What system are you doing this one? It works for me on PC with Firefox.

Comment: On Chrome (latest version), Windows 11. It would be helpful if you could provide a GIF.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #70](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/70)

Let’s say you wanted to quote a source fence. If you press the quote button, having the source fence selected, it has a double effect:

- It keeps adding quotes on the triple backtick lines  ```;
- It adds and removes the quotes on the remaining lines.

The result after six clicks looks like this:

````
> 
> > > ```
> some text
> > > ```
````

[image: Pressing the quote button on a source fence three times]

Comment: Is the trailing space in the first line with `>` intentional? Is it crucial for this example?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum the space is added by the system when you press quote, the system adds `> ` not just `>` which is consistent with CommonMark to add a space between quote and text. But you have to select the empty line before pressing the quote button. (I think the space and empty line add depth to the example.)

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #21](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21)

#### Headings created by dashes or equal signs under the line are only shown as headings in Markdown mode if there are at least two such characters

The rich-text mode previews this as a heading, regardless of the number of such characters.  This is the correct behavior, per the [relevant section of the CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#example-83).

[image: Screen recording of toggling between Markdown and rich-text mode to demonstrate the above bug]

Note that no editing is required in the above demonstration of this bug, as toggling Markdown mode collapses the heading underline into a single character (thus greatly increasing the likelihood of this bug being hit).

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #183](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/183)

Standard HTML (when used to add different heading levels in the header of a **table**) does not render properly in the rich text view. Moreover, switching back to Markdown completely destroys the table:

[image]

It only renders the HTML **after** posting the answer (provided you've not switched back to Markdown before posting).

Test:

| ### left | ## right |
| --- | --- |

---

Compare with the old editor (the HTML is properly rendered in the preview):

[image]

---

Also reported [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363974/513150) to *Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor*.

Comment: Tables don't behave nicely with previews already, might be either an existing bug or related to one?

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #186](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/186)

Highlighting a line of backticks ```` ``` ```` and trying to turn it into block code produces broken markdown:

[image]

Correct ways to format block code which contains three backticks would include:

1. Using four backticks

`````
````
```
````
`````

2. Using tildes

````
~~~
```
~~~
````

3. Using indentation

````
    ```
````

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #185](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/185)

Using the Markdown editor, if you try to quote a table the leading pipes are removed on all lines except the separator row. First click:

```
> 
> Column A | Column B |
> | -------- | -------- |
> Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
> Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
>
```

[image: quote and unquote a table 1 click]

If next you try to unquote the greater than `>` quote character isn't removed from the separator row. Further clicks of the quote button will repeat the process, adding more quote characters to the separator row. After 7 clicks:

```
> 
> Column A | Column B |
> > > > | -------- | -------- |
> Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
> Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
>
```

[image: quote and unquote a table 7 clicks]

#### GIF for reference

[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Allow saving edits to a post using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, like in the old editor.

Users used to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would be quite annoyed every time a newline is entered instead...

---

Also requested [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360075/513150) to *Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor*.

Comment: I continue to mess this up regularly (i.e., nearly every time I try to save a post on Teams).

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #191](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/191)

Pressing the down arrow key in a code block with multiple lines moves out of the code block, instead of down to the next line in the code block:

[image: GIF of using the new Stacks editor, with a code block with two lines. The cursor is initially placed on the first line, then it jumps to underneath the bottom of the code block.]

In this video I pressed these keys: <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

When I went to edit [my answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419174/15497888). When in preview mode (not markdown) the bare links **in a list** were prefixed with a loading spinner.

Toggling between markdown and back does not resolve this:

[image: GIF of a Meta Stack Overflow answer editor in preview mode with bare Meta Stack Overflow links to other questions in an unordered list prefixed with a loading spinner]

I let it spin for 12 minutes so it doesn't seem like it is going to resolve. (It also doesn't look like any type of request was made to be resolved?) If this is supposed to indicate that these links will be changed when submitted we should *really* have a different indicator than a loading spinner.

This only seems to impact bare links in lists.

Here's [another example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418437/15497888):

[image: Another GIF of a Meta Stack Overflow answer editor in preview mode with bare Meta Stack Overflow links to other questions in an unordered list prefixed with a loading spinner]

Removing the list removes the spinner. Putting the list back restores the spinner (whether the lists are restored through markdown or with the UI):
[image: GIF moving bare links out of unordered list and the spinner disappears. Click to restore list makes the spinner reappear]

Some more answers which show loading spinners on MSO:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296145/15497888
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288152/15497888
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333519/15497888

---

Curiously, I was unable to reproduce this in a [new answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380378/1099857) (nor in this answer itself):

Either on the initial post:
[image]

Or on an edit after:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #21](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21)

Preview does not support lang-* notation for syntax highlighting specification:

[image: 4 code blocks. 1. lang-python (no highlighting) 2. python (highlighted) 3. lang-java (no highlighting) 4. java (highlighting)]

However all highlight correctly when it is posted:

```python
print('test')
```

```python
print('test')
```

```java
System.out.println("test");
```

```java
System.out.println("test");
```

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #152](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/152)

Switching from Markdown to rich text mode strips blank lines in a variety of cases. For example writing this in Markdown mode:

```
<!-- some HTML comment -->

paragraph
```

has the empty line stripped when switching to rich text mode:

```
<!-- some HTML comment -->
paragraph
```

According to CommonMark specification blank lines don't break blocks, so the editor should keep blank lines when switching modes because the users may want to use them to visually break walls of text in the source.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #189](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/189)

When trying to delete multiple tables in the rich text view, only **one** table is deleted at a time.

Here's a GIF demonstrating the deletion of multiple tables at once (using manual selection):

[image]

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to delete all the tables works.

If there is text *above* the **first** table, then all the tables can be deleted at the same time, as intended:

[image]

---

Also reported [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360064/513150) to *Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor.*

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [GH #201](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/201)

As I asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379265/new-stacks-editor-incorrectly-renders-tag-markup-with-disallowed-characters-as-v), tag markdown displays differently in Stacks Editor than it does in Meta SO:

> When I typed `[tag:*-faq]` in the new stacks editor, it rendered as a tag (like [asterisk-faq](/questions/tagged/asterisk-faq)), but then when I posted my answer, the unrendered Markdown was displayed.
>
> Further, the Markdown following the asterisk was also italic.
>
> **Screenshot showing Stacks editor Markdown:**
> [image: Screenshot showing Stacks editor Markdown]
>
> **Screenshot showing Stacks editor rendered Markdown:**
> [image: Screenshot showing Stacks editor rendered Markdown]
>
> **Screenshot showing how Markdown was rendered on Meta SO:**
> [image: Screenshot showing how Markdown was rendered on Meta SO]

Comment: You would probably need to escape the asterix, as it being a markdown character in itself. Don't know if this is status-by-design though.

Comment: @Luuklag If it's status-bydesign, it's inconsistent. If it's going to render correctly in Stacks Editor, it should render correctly on the site. I've got no qualms either way whether it's valid syntax or not, the rendering just needs to be consistent after you've clicked the submit button.

Comment: That is a whole separate topic. Server side rendering, and client side rendering are two different things, there have been inconsistencies between the two as long as I can remember. But yeah, ideally they should both do the same things with the same syntax.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #202](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/202)

When editing an answer on mobile, and opening the image uploader there isn't enough room for all contents:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Cursor disappears in long posts

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #206](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/206)

(Reposting from [Can't use Stacks editor for long posts on iOS because the cursor disappears](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378749/323179) because there is no GitHub issue yet.)

This is really a serious bug. When I try to edit text towards the end of a long post (or sometimes middle, for very long posts), my cursor disappears. Where exactly this happens seems to depend on where the scroll bar is.

I can't see where I'm typing except that text appears (or disappears, when backspacing), and trying to move around my cursor is hopeless because tapping doesn't make it appear and neither does holding the spacebar. I can't see if I have any text selected either (as I sometimes end up deleting the entire body of the post). Examples of a few answers where this happened:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/323179)
- [Allow 'improve' for Tag Wiki Edit Suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96233/323179)
- [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82702/323179)
- [‘Remove wiki’ showing when a question is not a wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366708/323179)
- My answer about [tables and accessibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418553/6083675), which isn't even that long or complicated.
- [Another answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380286/323179), which only uses bullets and a horizontal rule for formatting and also isn't really that long
- This answer (can't edit the last paragraph or below that at all, can only sometimes see my cursor in the paragraph above that; nothing below the image has a cursor in WYSIWYG mode)
- The accepted answer on this question where I'm supposed to add a link to this answer

Cursor is between *community* and the period when I was backspacing:

[image: cursor missing from CW FAQ answer]

I tested it on two different browsers (iOS Chrome and iOS Safari) on different devices and it happens on both. It also happens on the [preview editor](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/). (I have not encountered this on desktop, which is the device I have to switch to in order to make edits.) It doesn't happen on every answer, only when the answer is long or maybe has some complicated formatting. It also seems to happen in both editor modes.

Significantly, this is preventing me from editing something on a private Team (where this is the only editor, and I also see this happening on questions), so it should be fixed.

Comment: Please add the iOS version you are using and the versions of Chrome and Safari. Given the relatively large number of issues with iOS and browsers not rendering things correctly, it would be quite helpful for you to be explicit about which versions of those you're using, so people can clearly see that you're using a version which is officially supported by SE. Alternately, that they are able to know things are broken on older browsers/iOS versions and that can be taken into account with respect to choices for what to support and documenting what is supported/known not working.

Comment: iOS 15.5-15.6 (possibly earlier), Google Chrome 103.0.5060.63, and I didn't think Safari has its own version, so it's just whatever comes with those iOS versions. I can't really put this information where I want in the answer :/

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #192](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/192)

### Inserting a horizontal rule in Markdown mode makes the previous line a header

Dashes under a line in Markdown apply header formatting.  There needs to be a blank line between the text and the row of dashes.  The existing editor handles this correctly.

[image: Screen recording showing the cursor at the end of a line in Markdown mode. The horizontal rule button is clicked, causing header formatting to be applied due to the line of dashes appearing on the next line. This is then previewed in rich-text mode.]

Also, minor related note: toggling between Markdown mode and regular mode changes the number of dashes from three to one (not a meaningful change).

Comment: Just to add context here– hyphens `-` (or equal signs `=`) below any text are _supposed_ to create a header [per CommonMark spec](https://commonmark.org/help/). I think it gets used accidentally more often than intentionally, but it's still valid Markdown all the same.

Comment: I think a good solution here would be for the horizontal rule button to insert a line break before the `---`, which would avoid creating an accidental heading.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #194](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/194)

#### Various oddities occur when a numbered item is a child of a bulleted item

This is based on the following Markdown:

```
- Bulleted item
  1. Numbered item
```

The following problems occur:

1. Selecting the bulleted item and pressing the bullet button does nothing.  This may or may not be expected. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
2. Selecting the numbered item shows *both* the bullet button and the number button selected. This may or may not be expected, as it is technically within a bulleted item [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). Pressing the number button removes the number, as expected.
3. Unexpectedly, pressing the bullet button *also* removes the number.  Pressing it a second time removes it from the parent bulleted item, as expected. [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)
4. The first bullet cannot be backspaced.  Doing so with something else before the bullet (not shown in this video) causes the cursor to move to that.  This may or may not be expected, as it's somewhat unclear what should happen to the child when the parent bullet is removed. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) However, if it is *not* the first item in the bulleted list, then the bullet *can* be backspaced.  The behavior should be consistent. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
5. Backspacing the bullet in this scenario results in the rich-text editor showing the formerly bulleted item's text indented until Markdown mode is toggled on and off, at which point it is no longer indented. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

[image: Screen recording of the above issues being demonstrated in order]

Comment: This is a tricky scenario, and we will try overall to make things more consistent. However, I am pretty sure that it is by design that you cannot backspace to cancel the root list item when there are nested items beneath it (will update if it should be changed).

Comment: And in the case where you are removing the second list item that has a sub-item, the sub-item now is a child item of the first bullet item (but the cursor is still in the intervening row), which is the reason for #5.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### Undo/Redo buttons don't always work

I guess this could be considered one bug or two, but I'm just reporting it once.

#### In the editor currently on SE, switching modes destroys the undo/redo stack.

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I can undo and redo changes in the mode I used to make them, but switching to the other mode resets the undo/redo stack so pressing the undo/redo buttons do nothing.

For example, you type some text in markdown mode and undo and redo work. The second you flip the switch to preview mode, pressing undo and redo no longer do anything. If you type more now, you can undo to what it looked like when you switched but not before that.

##### GIF for reference

[image: gif demonstrating the issue above]

#### In the [most up to date editor](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/), the undo/redo buttons do nothing

They just don't work.

> There is an issue with undo/redo on the demo editor, but it works fine on the site. — Yaakov Ellis

---

Reproduced in iOS Chrome, Windows 11 Chrome, MacOS Chrome. Leave a comment if you can reproduce elsewhere. Note that you will need to be in "narrow mode" to see the undo/redo buttons.

Comment: Due to the way in which the editor works in both modes, losing the undo/redo stack is a known issue but one that we are not planning on addressing. Maintaining the same stack untouched would not be good, as it would not be able to handle properly all scenarios where changes were made in the other mode. And there is no reliable way for us to change the stack in the non-active mode based on changes made in the current mode.

Comment: I'll see if possible for us to only lose the stack if changes are made in the other mode, and maintain it when a double-toggle is made with no other changes. Will update here if that is possible.

Comment: There is an issue with undo/redo on the demo editor, but it works fine on the site.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Either the help icon shouldn't direct you to Markdown help in rich text mode, or the help page should mention both Markdown and rich text.

[image: Screenshot of the editor in rich text mode with the tooltip for the help icon shown]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Applying a [numbered / bulleted] list to multiple lines works differently in each mode

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type text on multiple lines with single line breaks.
2. Select all lines.
3. Apply [Numbered / Bulleted] list to the selected text in Markdown mode.
4. Repeat using double line breaks.
5. Repeat the above in rich text mode.
6. Observe the difference.

---

##### GIFs for reference:

1. **Single** line break applied:

   [image]
2. **Double** line break applied:

   [image]

---

##### What's happening in Markdown mode?

- After selecting and applying a **numbered** list, the numbers assigned to each line are the **same**. Switching to rich text [and back to Markdown] fixes the numbering. This is not a bug, [as Marijn notes below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release/380604#comment1269775_380604), but it would be nice to have it apply the proper numbering in the first go itself.
- Compared to rich text mode (and the old editor), the numbering is applied to **all** the lines. In the case of bulleted lists, the bullet points are also applied to all the lines in Markdown mode.
- In the case of double line breaks, the [numbers / bullet points] are applied to blank spaces as well (as shown in the GIF above).

##### What's happening in rich text mode?

- After selecting all the lines, with either single or double line breaks, and applying a numbered list in rich text mode, the numbering is only applied to the **first item** in the list, as is the case in the old editor. This is also the case with bulleted lists.

---

#### Comparison with the old editor

[image]

Comment: The numbers in Markdown being the same (all 1) is not a bug, that is in the spec (see https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#lists-1 for examples). It is however somewhat annoying (but not harmful in this specific case afaics) that going from Markdown to rich text and back does not preserve the original input.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #207](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/207)

When translating a combination of `p` tag element and HTML comment on the MD mode, RT mode display transcribes texts weirdly:

- Overlap with the placeholder text
- Wrap in a blue border box
- Uneditable. Inserting new words make the whole text deleted.

In MD mode, insert this:

```
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<!--This is a comment -->
```

Result in RT mode:
[image]

Even back to the MD mode and deleting the HTML comment, the issue is still remaining.

Expect: Having a HTML comment shouldn't affect displaying the text in RT mode.

Comment: Related: [HTML comment inserts blue bar on top of post in rich text mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380409/665544)

Comment: I guess the overlap with the placeholder text would (currently) only be an issue in the [demo editor](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/), not in the editor that is being used on this site, which doesn't have placeholder text.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #196](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/196)

#### Adding a link to text with a space at the end causes the space to be included in the link text

This can happen, for instance, when you double-click a word to select it.  The old editor handles this correctly, trimming the portion that gets the link applied to not have any whitespace at the end.

[image: A screen recording of the above-described bug]

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [GH #193](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/193)

In rich text mode if you click to edit and cancel a link the tool is left at the bottom and doesn't reset its position back to under the link. Steps to reproduce:

1. Click Edit link

[image: edit link tool]

2. Next click Cancel

[image]

3. The link edit tool didn't reset its position back to underneath the link where the cursor is; it's left dangling where the previously expanded tool dialog ended.

[image]

#### **GIF for reference**:

[image]

---

System specific info: Firefox 102.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10. Rev at the time that I originally posted this.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Not sure if this is intended or not, but only **one** spoiler can be revealed at a time in the **rich text** view:

[image]

This does **not** happen *after* posting the answer.

Test:

> I can

> see

> multiple spoilers

> at the same time

> but only after

> posting the answer

---

Compare with the old editor (it's possible to see all the spoilers at the same time in the preview itself):

[image]

Comment: This is by design. If spoilers permanently revealed themselves when entered you wouldn't know if you were editing a spoiler or a blockquote. This is ultimately a consequence of the same design being used for both nodes, so this might be something we can revisit if/when we update the spoiler design.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #195](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/195)

In rich text mode having an HTML comment at the top of a post causes the editor to display a blue horizontal bar -if you move the cursor on that line in the editor- for example:

```
<!-- some HTML comment -->
paragraph
```

Causes the blue bar:

[image: blue bar in rich text editor]

This shouldn't happen since a comment shouldn't cause a visual queue in the editor?!

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [GH #101](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/101)

##### Make the resize tool more (visually) accessible.

In the new editor, the resize tool is denoted by two small diagonal lines in the bottom right corner of the editor:

[image]

This can be quite easy to miss. For users using the **non-inline** edit screen, in some cases, the resize tool (for resizing to see more of the *question*) is *barely* visible:

[image]

---

In the **old** editor, the resize tool is more visible:

[image]

---

Related [to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361784/513150) to *Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor*.

Comment: Just FYI: While I haven't checked, those look like the browser-based resize indicator which is displayed based on the `resize` CSS property. It's drawn on the inside of the element on which the property exists. In order for there not to be overlap between it and the contents of the element, there needs to be space specifically allocated to it within the element's layout. The easiest way to do so is to have some `padding` which leaves space for the indicator, although it's possible to use other methods of excluding, or pre-using, the necessary space.

Comment: The above is just information. IMO, the "grippie" bar (SE's name for it in the HTML/CSS), which exists on the current editor, provides a better UX.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #198](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/198)

In rich text mode a horizontal rule, `<hr>`, does not have a selection highlight whereas surrounding paragraphs have it. (This can be compared to [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380409) where an HTML comment does have a selection highlight.)

[image: Screenshot of text and hr selected]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When uploading an image the license is written in small case **cc by-sa** but for consistent styling with the rest of SE it should be capitalized as **CC BY-SA**.

[image: license in image upload dialogue]

I've written a previous post about the same bug in the footer [cc by-sa in footer should be capitalized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380148/665544)

Comment: This has been updated, both in the editor as well as in the [all other mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380538/51) on the site.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

It would be nice if in rich text the language code shown in the upper right corner of a source fence could be correctly stylized as Python, CSS, JavaScript instead of python, css, javascript, etc...

[image: rich text editor language code hint]

I know the tags are all lower case but I haven't found a post with explicit rules about casing because apparently writing `Python` instead of `python` in the language code of the source fence works all the same. But writing `Python` in sentence case still makes the language code show in lower case in the editor.

Comment: We dont have a programmatic way of determining the proper casing for language names (and some languages define themselves with all lower-case names), so would rather not get into a scenario where the language names have to be manually mapped. Would rather stay consistent here, and even with lower-case, it should be understandable what language is being used.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #197](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/197)

This bug is the opposite of [GitHub issue#41](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/41).

In rich text mode, if the first element in a post is a source fence, there's no way to insert a blank line before it, anything you type gets inserted inside the fence. (The proposed <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd> workaround escapes the fence downward but not upward.)

I consider this a breaking bug since the only obvious workaround for rich text users is deleting the entire fence to be able to insert something else at the beginning of the post.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #199](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/199)

In rich text mode, having an horizontal rule after a source fence, if you move the cursor down <kbd>↓</kbd> it visually pushes the `<hr>` down one line each time you go over it. Start like this:

[image: source fence and horizontal rule]

````
```
text in fence
```
---
````

After passing the cursor over the `<hr>` twice by pressing  <kbd>↓</kbd> here's a  picture of the horizontal rule having moved 2 lines, if you switch to Markdown no blank lines were introduced.

[image: source fence and horizontal rule after passing cursor over it twice]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #200](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/200)

In rich text mode, when selecting a link and moving upwards, the link dialogue is also moved up vertically to under blocks that aren't links.

Start like this:

[image]

Then move up:

[image]

#### GIF for reference

[image]

Comment: @Justin good point, the dialogue gets moved onto empty lines also.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Bolded message in Markdown is already bolded.

[image]

Shouldn't it be unbolded when in Markdown?

Comment: This is entirely intentional. The Markdown view displays as much formatting as it can while still displaying the actual Markdown. Many other styles will also appear as you type in Markdown view (like the links directly above the bolded text).

Comment: @animuson While I understand it's intentional, what this report indicates is that showing is as formatted can be confusing to users expecting to see Markdown text without formatting. Users may think things either aren't working correctly and/or that they need to remove what appears to be redundant Markdown formatting (it's already bold, right?). What this report should be taken as is indicating a need to document and explain how it's supposed to work somewhere within the UI (or that any currently existing documentation/explanation doesn't effectively communicate to some number of users).

Comment: @animuson I, also, had at least a moment of confusion when first using this editor due to it applying *some* formatting to text in Markdown mode. It was resolved by experimenting enough to see that the editor was applying *some of* the Markdown formatting. However, it was counter to my expectations for a Markdown editor, and *still* gives a "that's strange" feeling, even after 2 years of intermittent use, because nearly every other place where I see Markdown used (i.e. not just SE) *doesn't do that*, so there's a strong counter-expectation, which results in "something's wrong" feeling.

Comment: @Makyen Most Markdown editors I've ever used actually do format in this manner, so SE was the exception from most of my personal experiences. I get it's an adjustment for people who aren't used to it, but once you are, there are many benefits to showing some of the formatting in Markdown mode too. If you have suggestions for how to make it clear that it's intentional, we're all ears, but I can't really think of any ways to emphasize that.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Update the `Alpha` label to the `Beta` label in the [Preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> YE: as noted in the comments, the stacks editor on MSE and MSO only shows up when posting or editing answers. Asking questions continues to only use the old editor

---

In the original announcement it said:

> You can opt out at any time but it **will take up to 10 minutes** to revert to the old editor

After I go to the preferences page the Stacks editor is activated for answers but not for asking questions. For example, **I opted in over 1 hour ago** but the ask question dialogue still looks like this:

[image: editor in question]

while at the same time if I try to edit an answer the Stacks editor is already activated:

[image: editor in answer]

@Glorfindel explained in the comments:

> The new editor is only active for answering, not for asking ...

So my question is when will Stacks editor be activated for questions?

Comment: The new editor is only active for answering, not for asking ...

Comment: @Glorfindel is that explained somewhere, I tried reading through those massive threads several times and never found that explanation.

Comment: It's not 100% obvious, but this question states "The editor will continue to be available on Stack Overflow for Teams, and for **answering questions** on Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange".

Comment: @Glorfindel well that explains why I could never figure out why it worked sometimes, other times not, and the 10 minutes seemed to turn into a whole day.

Comment: @bad_coder It was also mentioned in the TLDR of the original announcement post: _"**Note, the new editor will only be active when drafting or editing answers** on MSE or MSO during the alpha test."_ (emphasis _not_ mine).

Comment: It's confusing since I was using Teams, MSE and MSO main and meta, and apparently I missed that 1 sentence...

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Shouldn't we be able to drag the question right above the answer? It’s easier for mobile users.

[image]

Comment: Please give more info on your setup. I cant reproduce this.

Comment: @YaakovEllis what do you mean? I'm not able to drag the question to see the whole question, as you can see I only can see partially of the question when answering in my screenshot

Comment: I believe you. I cannot reproduce it on any device or mobile testing mode. Whenever I try to, I am able to drag to see the question about without any issue. Hence my inquiry as to your setup/device/browser.

Comment: Oh wait I just realise I could drag it, problem is that the drag slider is at the bottom right corner of question as a tiny dot, so its impossible to spot @YaakovEllis

Comment: So sorry for causing you inconvenience @YaakovEllis I'll check more carefully next time

Comment: In that case, this is covered by [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380441/51) already, and [GH #101](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/101)

Comment: Not really @YaakovEllis, this is the question slider,not the answer slider

Comment: Both use the same `resize` css property. But if you notice carefully, I *do* talk about the question slider in that answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

[image]

The placeholder text in the edit summary seems to be missing a bracket, or at least for us mobile users.

Comment: It's not missing a bracket, rather, due to the narrow screen size, only part of the placeholder text is being shown. The full text reads: *briefly explain your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting)*

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Since many SE sites support mathematical formulas, a visual formula editor can be added as an editor feature.

Comment: We will be tackling per-site plugins at a later release, with the goal of achieving parity on all sites with the functionality of the current editor. This will be done before we can begin to test network-wide. I am marking this as declined right now because - while it is on the roadmap - it is not part of the current scope of work.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Lets say we have some text, pressing the buttons in the editor:

1. **Bold it**
2. *Italicize it*
3. ***Italicize first, then bold***
4. **On bold italics press italics once** (Italics is removed)
5. *On bold press italics* (Bold is removed)

In the last (5th) step bold is removed instead of having italics added to the existing bold. I think this isn't the expected outcome, when you press italics on a text (bolded or not) that isn't italicized it should become italicized instead of removing the bold.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

In the image upload dialogue the **Imgur** logo is slightly misaligned with the preceding text. I also think it doesn't look good overall with the remaining fonts and other elements:

[image: Powered by Imgur]

Comment: The actual display of this on screen is very small. It may be one pixel off when you magnify it (as you have done), but the overall presentation of it when not magnified appears to have all of the text inline.

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Using the old editor I seemed to notice **a sort was sometimes applied** to the numbered links upon submitting - meaning the link numbers would be changed by the system to be numbered by order of appearance in the post. (I tried searching for an explanation but could never find a post explaining it.)

So I would expand on @RyanM's [natural sorting FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380305) and ask that in the following example the link numbers be sorted 1, 2, 3 in the both in the references and the reference list under the post. So if you wrote the following:

```
1st paragraph [link 1][3]
2nd paragraph [link 2][2]
3rd paragraph [link 3][1]

[2]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380333
[1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380336
[3]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380331
```

The system would convert it to:

```
1st paragraph [link 1][1]
2nd paragraph [link 2][2]
3rd paragraph [link 3][3]

[1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380331
[2]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380333
[3]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380336
```

And why would this be advantageous? For a couple of reasons:

1. It would allow the OP to just insert any link numbers without having to worry if you're getting the sequence numbering right! (Notice that if the OP now wanted to change the post and insert link#4 at the very top, they needn't worry about renumbering or sorting the links they had inserted previously.)
2. This would make post **maintainability** (editing) a lot more convenient. For example if you're editing [a massive post](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/16) with +140 links, keeping the numbering synced would guaranteed the link numbers you see below and above link 123, are indeed 122 and 124 as you they occur in the post (so the editor needn't worry about keeping track of things).

Comment: I substantially disagree with this. Auto-renumbering and/or reordering the link references makes post edit diffs very hard for a human to review. It *substantially* expands on what the *actual* change was and effectively hides that actual change within a bunch of noise. While I might agree that there should be the ability for the user to manually choose to have the links auto-reordered, I *strongly* disagree that this should be something that is routinely auto-applied.

Comment: @Makyen I would say the problem might be with how the diff viewer presents the change. If the diff highlighted a single char instead of the whole line that's mostly unchaged, it would make inspection of newly added lines trivial. But good very good point, I hadn't thought of how diff view adds to the problem.

Comment: While there could be substantial improvements in the diff viewer, there isn't a reasonable set of improvements in it which would fully cover the auto-renumbering and auto-resorting which is proposed here (other than the diff being coded to specifically handle things in reference lists, which isn't appropriate, IMO).

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph: Basically, if you use the automatic list formatting applied by the old editor, then anytime you add a new link (I think?), that editor will automatically update the numbers used (for all links formatted in this way) depending on the order in which the links appear in the body text. For example, if the post reads "[This][2] is a [link][1]", and then you add a link somewhere in the post with Ctrl+L (or Cmd+L on Mac), then the link labels will change: "[This][1] is a [series][2] of [links][3]". I think this relabeling only happens when you add a new link, though.

Comment: ...That said, I think the Stacks editor uses inline links (i.e. `[like this](https://example.org/)`) by default when you hit Ctrl/Cmd+L, rather than the "reference-style" links (i.e. `[like this][1]`, with `[1]: https://example.org/` at the end of the post) that the old editor uses by default.

Comment: @V2Blast I tried finding a post explaining the renumbering rule several times (over maybe a good couple of hours) **but** I haven't found an explanation posted yet. I've seen it happen on my own posts, yet I can't explain the rules or conditions that make it happen. I never use shortcuts, my links are all hand crafted... Sometimes it happens other times not...

Comment: This would require a **significant** amount of work. We might consider exploring it more if there was a strong community consensus around it, but until then, going to have to decline it.

Answer (score 0):

<s>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)</s> [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Please don't include a button that makes text unreadable:

> The general consensus in the web accessibility community is that CSS strikethrough text is not accessible, as the strikethrough decoration is typically ignored by screen readers and the text is read out loud without any indication of a strikethrough. In addition, it can be difficult for screen magnification users or users with low vision to see what the text is, or figure out what text is crossed out. — [Veroniiiica](https://veroniiiica.com/2020/05/29/tips-for-censoring-text-with-accessibility-in-mind/)

Instead of using strikethrough, an author should either delete the text or reword so that the post works without using strikethrough.

Note: While there is no strikethrough button on the current beta editor, there's one on the [preview](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/md-preview.html) page editor.

Comment: We aren't including a strikethrough button on the site right now. So I dont have much to respond to here.

Comment: @YaakovEllis so that makes this status-completed, right?

Comment: Well, we didn't complete anything though…

Comment: No-repro then because there is no button? @YaakovEllis /exit ocd mode

Comment: I think to make this no longer no-repro, this can be phrased as "please cancel any potential future plans to add a strikethrough button".