# In the new editor, always show the undo/redo buttons, not only on smaller screen widths, to accommodate tablet users and avoid breaking workflows

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, undo, stacks-editor

Currently, the buttons to undo and redo are only shown on lower screen widths, to accommodate mobile users, as undoing and redoing is hard/impossible for them to do. They're hidden on higher widths, as it's assumed the user is on a desktop or laptop and can easily use the keyboard shortcut.

However, for users of tablets, undoing and redoing is just as difficult as on a smaller mobile device, especially if the operation is to be performed repeatedly. The same also applies to touchscreen computer users where using the keyboard is inconvenient (e.g. laptops folded completely on themselves).

Also, the old editor always shows the undo and redo buttons even on larger widths, so it's possible users may be used to using them with their mouse. I also made use of the visual indication of them being enabled/disabled to determine whether or not I could use the keyboard shortcut (currently broken until [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380329/377214) is fixed).

The buttons to undo and redo should always show regardless of screen width, not only on smaller widths. (I mean, there's *definitely* enough room...)

Further details are in the [GitHub issue report](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/210).

Answer (score 8):

I have *partially* resolved this request. More details are in comments on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/210), so I'll directly quote them here:

> I thought on this a bit and I added support for these buttons to show on all devices that need virtual keyboards. I had to do a bit of testing to hit as many corner cases as possible, but support isn't 100% perfect due to the way browsers present themselves, especially in the case of convertible devices.

> [We're not showing the buttons all the time] because currently the menu is much too crowded, so adding even a single new icon with the undo/redo buttons present will cause the menu to overflow. In the demo site's case, it's the "strikethrough" button. In the case of production, it'd be e.g. the Snippets button.
> We're looking at potentially making some changes to the menu layout, so if we are able to gain back some space, then we'll revisit showing the history buttons all the time.

Since the request is to show the buttons all the time and my solution is not exactly that, I'm marking this as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). If the given solution is an acceptable compromise, please drop a comment and I can update this request to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).