# Empty editor when editing an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, stacks-editor

When I edit an answer (mine or somebody else's) with the [new Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/295232), the answer's Markdown does not appear in the editor. It remains blank:

[image]

Questions don't have this problem (those use the old editor) and it does not matter which mode (Markdown / Rich Text / Markdown + Preview) I'm in. It happens in various browsers, so it's not caused by one of my userscripts.

I'm pretty sure this is a recent bug, as it used to work fine this morning.

Comment: Looks like userscript going rogue, I've never seen such editor, so something on your side is messing with SE editor, big time.

Comment: that's a lot of additional editor scripts there.

Comment: No, it's the [new Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/295232). No scripts attached :)

Comment: There is different tag for that, and many people don't use it. Personally, I don't have high hopes, from the lack of attention, more likely it will be sunset at some point, having too many bugs. (So I don't bother to try it.) (That said, as I don't use it myself, can't vote on this bug report, for good and for bad. ;))

Comment: Probably related on MSO: [Blank edit text area on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421039)

Comment: It's the new new Stacks editor, last time I checked we had a visual or markdown toggle, now there appears to be a third option in the top right corner.

Comment: @ErikA it's markdown + preview.

Comment: Ah, I see that's been added last month, I had missed that.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it but also I've seen enough bugs where the functionality is different for different users to not be surprised by this. Sometimes it's [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) other times related to a given post or actually a user. So me not reproducing it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Glorfindel the bug on Meta SO has disappeared on my PC, does this one still reproduce?

Comment: A similar issue was impacting the Stacks editor on Teams, and it seems like the issue has been fixed there. Are folks still experiencing this issue with the Stacks editor on MSE/MSO, or is it now working for y'all?

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not able to reproduce it now, but I've seen different build numbers in the footer throughout the day. When I posted this, it was a 2022.10.24.something build, a few minutes ago it was 2022.10.21.... and now it's 2022.10.24.26681 again. So it seems to depend on which server you hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was fixed in a release earlier this week.

The bug was introduced during a refactor of how we initialize the new Stacks Editor across various web pages. The intent of this refactor was to reduce the number of invocation paths and standardize on a base set of features to enable (one being the new Markdown Preview mode).

There were subtle differences in how our Teams product and various pages on the public site were using these methods, and this led to a blind spot in our testing with regards to editing content with the new editor.

Moving forward, we will now have the proper tests in place that cover this scenario (among others) and are working to surface the failures earlier in the development process to help prevent releasing regressions like this.

Apologies for the oversight. I'll take two demerits as punishment.

Comment: Teams. It's always Teams.